# How to calibrate volatility surface for Interest Rate Cap&Floor pricing

Tags: volatility, pricing, calibration, black

I'm using Black model to do interest rate Cap & Floor pricing.

The volatility is determined by using the bootstrapping methodology.

However, afterwards, how should I do the calibration, or surface smoothing?
Please can you kindly recommend papers and books about the topic?